# X1 Carbon Gen 6 cannot enter deep sleep

Tags: ubuntu, lenovo-laptop

When closing the lid sometimes it goes to sleep and sometimes not. After opening the lid again Dock on the right disappears!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  pressing Windows_Key + L  to lock your laptop before closing the lid. This will fix the problem until the proper BIOS update come out and fix it!

[image]